# Custom element fill paper-scroll-header-panel content height area

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the polymer starter kit, I removed class `content` and `iron-pages`. I am trying to make my custom element `<main-content>` to fill the view port of `paper-scroll-header-panel`.

How can I make the custom element fill the height(like 100%) of `paper-scroll-header-panel` content area **without** hard coding a `px` value?

index.html:

```
  <!-- Main Area -->
  <paper-scroll-header-panel main id="headerPanelMain" class="fit">
    <!-- Main Toolbar -->
    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
      <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>    

      <span class="space"></span>

      <!-- Application name -->
      <div class="middle middle-container">
         <div class="app-name"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Application sub title -->
      <div class="bottom bottom-container">
        <div class="bottom-title">John and Olivia are getting married!</div>
      </div>
    </paper-toolbar>

    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div>
        <section data-route="home">
          <main-content class="focus-target" tabindex="-1"></main-content>
        </section>
    </div>
  </paper-scroll-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

---

custom element:

```
<dom-module id="main-content">
  <template>
    <style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
      :host {
        height: 100%;
     }

      #main {
        background: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url('../img/main-background.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        min-width: 500px;
        min-height: 500px;
      }

    </style>
      <div id="main">
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'main-content'
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Note:** It's hard to see in the pic, but on the bottom there is a white bar where the element should be expanding that height of the viewport/panel

[image: custom element does not fill viewport]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the style in `<dom-module id="main-content">` from

```
<style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
  :host {
    height: 100%;
 }

  #main {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/main-background.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
  }

</style>
```

to

```
<style include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
  :host {
    @apply(--layout);
  }

  #main {
    background: black;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.meme.am/instances/65207274.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    @apply(--layout-flex);
  }

</style>
```

and for the

```
<div>
    <section data-route="home">
      <main-content class="focus-target" tabindex="-1"></main-content>
    </section>
</div>
```

add a class to make it identifyable

```
    <div class="main-content">
        <section data-route="home">
          <main-content class="focus-target" tabindex="-1"></main-content>
        </section>
    </div>
```

and add this to the `<head>` tag to apply styles to it and it's containing `<main-content>` element:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    .main-content,main-content {
      @apply(--layout-fit);
    }
</style>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QFI5wq3i9OMIhYac9oip?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could of figured that out. I never would of thought to do it like this.